# Swift Cancelling the ActivityViewController causes fatal error

Tags: ios, swift, option-type

Okay so I got my ActivityViewController to work fine when it is sharing like normal however whenever a user hits cancel after they invoked the ActivityViewController , I get the annoying fatal error.

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

So it looks like I did not unwrap my optionals well. Here's the share method :

```
@IBAction func share(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        var   memeedimage = generateMemedImage()


        let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems:[memeedimage] , applicationActivities: nil)
        presentViewController(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)


        activityViewController.completionWithItemsHandler = {
            (activity, success, returneditems, error) in
            println("Activity: \(activity) Success: \(success) Items: \(returneditems) Error: \(error)")
            self.save()

            activityViewController.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion:{
                let memevc:MemeTableViewController  = MemeTableViewController()
                self.presentViewController(memevc, animated: true, completion: nil)
                })
        }
```

and the share method calls the save function which generates the object called meme using an implicitly unwrapped optional which causes the error :

```
func save(){
        var meme : MemeObject!

          meme = MemeObject(textFieldtop : texfieldtop.text! ,textFieldbottom : textfieldbottom.text!  ,image : imagePickerView.image! , memedImage : generateMemedImage())
            (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).memes.append(meme!)

    }
```

So I decided to safely unwrap the meme optional value but that invoked another problem

```
 func save(){
        var meme : MemeObject?
        if let memez = meme{
          meme = MemeObject(textFieldtop : texfieldtop.text! ,textFieldbottom : textfieldbottom.text!  ,image : imagePickerView.image! , memedImage : generateMemedImage())
            (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).memes.append(meme!)
        }

        else{
            println("Optionals man")
        }

    }
```

Now when the the object is not nil , "Optionals man" is printed which shouldn't happen and the completionwithitemshandler property  in the share method didn't present the table view controller which should happen directly after the user shares the object.

Code for MemeTableViewController :

```
import UIKit

class MemeTableViewController : UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource
{
    var memesz: [MemeObject]!


    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!



    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {

            super.viewWillAppear(animated)
            let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
            memesz = appDelegate.memes
            //tableView.reloadData()


    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {


        super.viewDidLoad()
        navigationController?.hidesBarsOnSwipe = true
        navigationController?.hidesBarsOnTap = true

    }

    //reserves the number of rows needed to display the image
       func tableView(tableView : UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section : Int)->Int
       {

            return memesz.count

        }
    //Reserves the row to be dequeued for display
     func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell:TableViewzCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("MemesCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TableViewzCell
        let memezrow =  memesz[indexPath.row]
        cell.label1.text = memezrow.textFieldtop
        cell.label2.text = memezrow.textFieldbottom
        cell.imageview.image = memezrow.memedImage

            return cell
    }

    //Method to do something when the row is selected
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

        let detailController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("FullScreenMeme") as! FullScreenMeme
        detailController.meme = memesz[indexPath.row]
        self.navigationController!.pushViewController(detailController, animated: true)

    }

}
```

Any help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking your code, it seems like you haven't initialised the variable 'meme'.

```
func save(){
        var meme : MemeObject? =  MemeObject(textFieldtop : texfieldtop.text! ,textFieldbottom : textfieldbottom.text!  ,image : imagePickerView.image! , memedImage : generateMemedImage())

        if let memez = meme{
            (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).memes.append(meme!)
        }

        else{
            println("Optionals man")
        }

    }
}

@IBAction func share(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
var   memeedimage = generateMemedImage()


let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems:[memeedimage] , applicationActivities: nil)
presentViewController(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)


activityViewController.completionWithItemsHandler = {
    (activity, success, returneditems, error) in
    println("Activity: \(activity) Success: \(success) Items: \(returneditems) Error: \(error)")
    self.save()

    let memevc  = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MemeTableViewConroller") as! MemeTableViewController

    self.presentViewController(memevc, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
}
```

[image: rembember to set storyboardID]

Comment: Table View Controller still didn't get called after initialising 'meme' . Wonder why?

Comment: You don't need to call activityViewController.dismissViewControllerAnimated. I have edited my answer. Please have a look at it.

Comment: Okay now I think the ActivityViewController has called the TableViewController however I get a complete black screen after it gets called.

Comment: I don't know how MemeTableViewController is implemented, but you should call the correct initialiser.  Include the initialisers of MemeTableViewController to try to help you. Please accept my answer as correct.

Comment: I have updated my question .Please I really need to finish this project . MemeTableViewController is supposed to take the saved objects from the array in app delegate and display them.

Comment: Are you using storyboard or xibs?

Comment: I'm using storyboard.

Comment: Then you need to initialise MemeTableViewController using self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier,